# How to make TextBox to use password characters instead of using passwordbox in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Is there any change to make TextBox to use password characters instead of using passwordbox in wpf ?

```
<PasswordBox Height="42" Width="200"  Margin="22,28,28,0" 
     Name="passwordBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     Background="LightBlue" Foreground="DarkBlue" 
     MaxLength="25" PasswordChar="*" 
     />
```

with above code i can get the result what i need but I have to achieve the same result using textbox instead of passwordbox .what should i do for that.

Comment: Why can't you change to a `PasswordBox`? You can probably implement some kind of attached property for a `TextBox` that replaces the displayed characters with `*`, but it would be much simpler to just use a `PasswordBox`

Answer (score 2):

The TextBox does not have have a "password mode". PasswordBox is the only way to go.

Comment: As I said, not possible in WPF TextBox.

Answer (score -2):

You can change a textbox as a password box, by changing the property of textbox.

First you create a textbox and press F4. property will open. on that look for 'passwordchar' and change that into '*'. and change whatever you want,like maximum length.

I think it will help to you..

Comment: there is no passwordchar property

Comment: That is `WinForms`. He is asking about `WPF`.